# Is "give somebody a black look" idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

This often happens at school in Asia where teachers or school supervisors sometimes roll their eyes towards one side (to the left or right) to look at their students with anger, probably the students are doing something bad.

Or we often see that in kindergarten, for example, a child is trying to sneakily take some candies in a box and the teacher gives that kind of look to him/her.

Is it idiomatic and common to say "**to give somebody a black look**" or "**to give a black look to/at somebody**" to express the idea of to roll your eyes towards one side and look at somebody with anger/ jealousy or any negative attitude"?

For example,

> "*The teacher **gave a black look** at / to him as he was trying to sneakily take some candies in the box*"

**Note**: I am not sure I should use "**at**" or "**to**" because we have the structure "*to give something **to** somebody*" but "*to have a look **at** somebody*")

Also, can we use "**look askance**" for example,

> "She **looked askance at him** when he began to eat before everybody else."

but I am not sure this phrase is common or not.

Comment: Note: we **roll** our eyes.

Comment: Sometimes shorter titles are better, the details go in the body

Comment: The teacher gave **him** a black look. No: to or at. look askance is very literary.

Answer (score 1):

First, the word is "roll", not "role", to indicate movement of the eyes.
Your suggestion of "look askance" is about right for the expressions in your pictures.

[American Heritage Dictionary "askance"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=askance)

1. With disapproval, suspicion, or distrust: *The area is so dirty that merchants report the tourists are looking askance.*
2. With a sideways glance; obliquely.

I think "black look" is more negative.
[Cambridge "black look"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/black-look)
"an expression on your face that is full of anger and hate"

The pictures show something milder than hate, to me.

Comment: But is "look askance" a common everyday term or not many people know it?

Comment: It's not very common, but "black look" is even less common. There are many synonyms of both terms searchable on google, such as "frown", and "look skeptically" for "look askance", and "glower" for "black look". Also, you can use google ngram viewer to check the frequency of the terms in books.

Comment: I am looking for a common one that a child can learn.

Comment: Look for uses of "frown", a very common term.

Comment: Some people say  "glare at"? Can we use it instead of "look askance"? Is it common?

Comment: Yes, that's a little stronger than frown, but it's pretty common. The looks above are more like "askance", or "looking sidewise", though. A glare is looking more directly and angrily.

Comment: A colloquial expression for this is to **give someone the stink eye**.

Comment: @CanadianYankee, can we say "give/shoot somebody a dirty look":
"​(informal) to look at somebody in a way that shows you are annoyed with them"?

Comment: @CanadianYankee, "give someone the stink eye" is more general as it does not show how the eyes are positioned. What about "to give somebody an angry sideways glance / look"?

Comment: I'm surprised that no one mentioned ["side eye"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/side-eye)! That is another way to describe what the women in the pictures are doing.